# Trigger jQuery if URL contains ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several pages on a website that use hidden divs which are displayed when a section link is clicked (using `id=sectionname`). However, if someone goes straight to mysite.com/#sectionname, that section remains hidden unless the person clicks the link.

Is there a way to use jQuery to check if a div id is passed via the url, and trigger the click? Something along the lines of [not actual code]:

```
if ('# is in url') {
     $('#-characters-until-?').trigger("click");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check to see if `window.location.hash` is truthy.

```
if (window.location.hash) {
      // do something here
}
```

Comment: So if I was trying to run a trigger on a parent div, i could in theory use:
'jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
if (window.location.hash) {
      var id = window.location.hash;
      jQuery.id.parent().closest('.container-class').trigger("click");
};
});'
?

Comment: The user asking the question maybe didn't pick this answer, but I surely would, this check allows for a lot more flexibility if there are js changes also required along with just CSS (like assigning classes etc)

Answer (score 6):

You can also use pure CSS instead of javascript for showing section be default. For example:

```
section:target {
    display: block;
}
```

This rule uses [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) selector to select elements with id matching current `location.hash`. So if the url is `mysite.com/#sectionname` the rule above will show element with `section#sectionname`.

```css
div {display: none;}
div:target {display: block;}
```

```html
<a href="#test">test</a> <a href="#rest">rest</a>

<div id="test">TEST div</div>
<div id="rest">REST div</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var hash_link = location.hash;

//hash_link will return the id in the URL example: #myid

if(hash_link == '#myid'){
   //Do something
}
```

[W3schools] https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp